# Required value 'resultCombinationList' missing at $ (Android, Kotlin)

Tags: android, json, objetos, kotlin

estou tentando consumir uma API, com o seguinte formato JSON:

```
{ "USDBRL": {
"code": "USD",
"codein": "BRL",
"name": "Dólar Americano/Real Brasileiro",
"high": "5.567",
"low": "5.567",
"varBid": "0.0004",
"pctChange": "0.01",
"bid": "5.5666",
"ask": "5.5675",
"timestamp": "1642541401",
"create_date": "2022-01-18 18:30:01"} }
```

Pelo que entendi, retorna um objeto, com outro objeto dentro.

Criei minha classe de dados:

```
data class CoinResultRequest(
val resultCombinationList : Map<String, ConversionCombination>
){
constructor() : this(hashMapOf())}
```

Que contem o objeto com dados recebidos:

```
data class ConversionCombination(
@SerializedName("code")
val coinCode: String,

@SerializedName("codein")
val coinCodeIn: String,

@SerializedName("name")
val combinationName: String,

@SerializedName("high")
val high: String,

@SerializedName("low")
val low: String,

@SerializedName("varBid")
val varBid: String,

@SerializedName("pctChange")
val pctChange: String,

@SerializedName("bid")
val bid: String,

@SerializedName("ask")
val ask: String,

@SerializedName("timestamp")
val timestamp: String,

@SerializedName("create_date")
val create_date: String,)
```

Porém sempre acabo caindo no erro ao fazer a chamada na API,

```
Required value 'resultCombinationList' missing at $
```

Answer (score -2):

É bem simples de transformar um json em Objeto. O que você precisa é espelhar a classe corretamente conforme a estrutura do JSON.
No seu exemplo eu não entendi como você tentou transformar o JSON em objeto. Existe uma biblioteca muito boa chamada Gson, que faz esse trabalho, no [nesse link](https://github.com/google/gson) mostra como adicionar a biblioteca ao seu projeto.

Em resumo, faça a seguinte classe:

```
data class ValorMoeda (
val code: String,
val codein: String,
val name: String,
val high: String,
val low: String,
val varBid: String,
val pctChange: String,
val bid: String,
val ask: String,
val timestamp: String,
val createDate: String)
```

A Classe Usdbrl tem a mesma estrutura do objeto json. É preciso também criar uma classe com a estrutura do objeto raiz.

```
data class Conversao(@SerializedName("USDBRL", alternate=["EURBRL", "LIBBRL", "IENBRL"]) val valorMoeda: ValorMoeda)
```

Caso queira manter o nome da propriedade na classe diferente do nome no JSON, adicione a annotation SerializedName.

Por último transforme a sua string json em um objeto no kotlin

```
val item = Gson().fromJson(jsonText, Conversao::class.java)

println(item.toString())
```

[Nesse Tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/json-convert-data-class) tem mais detalhes de como fazer isso.

Comment: Sim, funciona dessa forma, porém dependendo da conversão, o "USDBRL" muda, e com outro nome na minha variável, ele não reconhece o objeto na hora do request com a API, como por exemplo, se fosse "EURBRL".

Comment: Coloque uma anotação sobre a propriedade da sua classe com o nome da propriedade do JSON. @SerializedName("USDBRL") val NomeDaPropriedade: Usdbrl

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Entendi Fábio, o problema está mesmo na parte que esse nome "USDBRL", muda conforme a conversão, se eu converter de euro pra real, o nome na API fica como "EURBRL", e após isso ele não consegue mais converter pra objeto, devido esse nome ser diferente..., ele só consegue converter se a propriedade do meu objeto for igual a propriedade da API.

Comment: Nesse caso pode por quais são os nomes alternativos, por exemplo @SerializedName(value="USDBRL", alternate=["EURBRL", "LIBBRL", "IENBRL"])
Pode ver o link abaixo, é um caso parecido com o seu: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25707728/multiple-gson-serializedname-per-field?rq=1

Comment: Show, resolvi usando a interface Map mesmo, (chave/valor). Mas muito obrigado por sua atenção!